# Can't find constructor on type; works in Watch

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, watch

This is the code I use:

```
Type type = /* retrieved Type */
object arg = /* something that evaluates to null */
MyClass obj = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg);
```

I get a crash, that given constructor doesn't exist on type **type**.

However, when I put this in Watch in Visual Studio 2008:

```
(MyClass)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, null)
```

it creates the object as usual.

I even tried replacing my code with the one I put in the Watch. It works - object gets created.

My question: what's up with that?

Edit: MyClass ***doesn't*** have any constructors - apart from pregenerated *parameterless* constructor.

Edit 2: Using `new object[0]` instead of `null` still causes the same exception.

Comment: Don't use the *var* keyword here if you don't like surprises.

Comment: OK, the actual code has the declaration of obj before this code. But I modified it anyway. I tried even discarding the return value of CreateInstance - still same exception.

Comment: He casts to `(MyClass)`, so I'd be highly surprised if `var` were not `MyClass`.

Comment: I updated the code. But it wouldn't throw the exception that constructor doesn't exist - it would throw exception that it can't cast object to MyClass.

Comment: Can you post the signature of the constructor you want to invoke?

Comment: MyClass doesn't have any constructor - so it should default to parameterless.

Comment: Then why are you passing `arg` to it?

Comment: The only difference I see is that `(object)` has a different static type than `null`. So this sounds like an overload resolution problem.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen: Because, actually I create about 3 different types of objects with that code, and to the most constructors I don't want to pass any arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into an issue with the `params` keyword.

The actual signature of the function is `CreateInstance(Type, object[])`. However, the fact that the `object[]` parameter is declared as `params` means that you can pass a variable number of arguments to the function and those arguments will get rolled into a new array, *or* you can directly pass an object array.

When the compiler performs overload resolution on the version where you pass `null` directly into the function, it does not convert the parameter into an array since `null` is a valid value for this. However, when you pass in a null-valued *object variable*, overload resolution has to turn that into an object array. This means that you are passing an object array with one value, which is `null`. The runtime then looks for a constructor with one argument, which it would then pass `null` to.

This is why the resolution fails at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use `Activator.CreateInstance(type, listStruct == null ? new object[0] : new object[] { listStruct })`, which is a bit stupid, but I'll settle with it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is using the following overload of the [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
public static Object CreateInstance(
    Type type,
    params Object[] args
)
```

Notice the `params` keyword.

Now let's take a look at your code:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, null)
```

This passes a null reference as `args`. In this case, the method looks for a parameter-less constructor.

```
object arg = // ...
Activator.CreateInstance(type, arg)
```

This passes a one-element array containing a null reference as `args`, because `arg` is declared as `object`. In this case, the method looks for a constructor with one parameter.

To avoid any ambiguity, call the method as follows:

```
object[] args = null;                            // 0 parameters
//  - or -
object[] args = new object[] { "Hello World" };  // 1 parameter

var result = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
```

Comment: So I should use new object[0] instead of null? Because that doesn't work either

Comment: No it doesn't, null is used for the array argument, meaning no arguments to the constructor, it does not mean *pass null as the argument to the constructor*. If you want that, use `new object[] { null }`

Comment: Well, but calling CreateInstance(type, arg) with arg = null should be the same as calling with new object[] { null } according to dtb, right? By the way, using 'new object[] { null }' still causes the same exception.

Comment: Only if arg is defined as an object array.